# Interpretation I dont know what to do?

Tags: math

I don't understand what I am supposed to do in this exercise, I am beginning programming contest, if you can help me is very appreciated, I have seen formulas, but I don't understand what to do, I feel very stupid , and for everyone is easy :(

http://www.codeforces.com/contest/1/problem/A

Comment: Is there anything specific you are having problems understanding?  The input, output, problem statement, something else?

Comment: problem statement I got problems

Comment: What progaramming language do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One little hint. Suppose that you must cover an *axn* rectangle with *axa* stones. Then the solution is "*k* stones", where *ka* is the first multiple of *a* greater than or equal to *n*. (Draw a picture.)

How to go for *k*? Do a division and have a look at the documentation of the `ceil()` function (it is quite standard).

Now what happens if we move to a 2-dimensional problem, i.e. if we have to cover an *mxn* rectangle? (Draw another picture, do some experiments.)

Comment: You're welcome. Actually it is better to solve the problem without involving floating point numbers or ceil(), that is, doing an _integer_ division and checking the remainder, but the underlying concept is that of "rounding the result up to the next integer".

Answer (score 1):

The site seems to be in Russian or English.  I'm guessing that neither of these is your first language.

The problem is to pave a rectangular area with square tiles.  You are given three values:

- length of the rectangular area
- width of the rectangular area
- size of the tiles (length of a side: remember they are square)

You must write a program that takes the three numbers above as inputs (on the command line) and provide the number of tiles required as output.

Comment: how do I obtain the output?, this is my question, the formula

Comment: That's not really an interpretation problem; it's what you're supposed to figure out for yourself.